# Using Format-Table in Register-ObjectEvent

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to display the last 20 lines of a csv file in tabular format when the file changes. To do this manually I have used `import-csv $FILENAME | select -last 20 | Format-Table` -This works

When I try to put this in an event watching for file changes

```
  $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
      cls
      write-host "File Changed"
      import-csv $($eventArgs.FullPath) | select -last 20 | Format-Table
  }
```

The write-host line works but the table is never displayed. If I break the piping up all steps work except the Format-Table.

What can I do to get the last 20 lines of the csv file to show in tabular format?

Edit:
Here is the full event object definition:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $searchPath
$watcher.Filter = $file
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
   cls
   write-host "File Changed"
   import-csv $($eventArgs.FullPath) | select -last 20 | Format-Table
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `format-table` exactly?. Perhaps adding  `Format-Table | Out-String` gets you what you want.

Comment: I did try that at one point - it still stops at the Format-Table section and I get no output. I am not stuck on Format-Table - any method of displaying the data in columns and rows will work.

Comment: @Matt Your comment did point me in the right direction though. I started just trying each of the different Out-*. Using Out-Host appears to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @Matt pointed me in the right direction. It appears that for some reason piping to Out-Host causes the output to display where Out-String or not piping does not.
The functioning code is as follows:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $searchPath
$watcher.Filter = $file
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
   cls
   write-host "File Changed"
   import-csv $($eventArgs.FullPath) | select -last 20 | Format-Table | Out-Host
}
```

This is essentially a tail for csv files.